# typescript duplicate import of 'moment'

Tags: typescript, momentjs

I am using momentjs in a typescript/React project. Currently I have these lines at the top of a file:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { Moment } from 'moment';
```

where `Moment` is the type of a moment, and `moment` is the moment object itself, e.g.:

```
let m: Moment = moment.now();
```

Now my typescript linter whinges: `Multiple imports from 'moment' can be combined into one. (no-duplicate-imports)tslint(1)`.

However I can't work out how to do that. Not sure how to have the `*` and `Moment` in the same import line...

Comment: Moment shouldn't be imported as a namespace (* as). It should be imported as a default export. `import moment from 'moment';` then you can write `import moment, {Moment} from 'moment';`. Always set `esModuleInterop: true` in tsconfig.json

Comment: Thanks - that worked. Will accept it as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by Aluan Haddad ,Try importing moment as default export. Then your importing will look fine using below

```
import moment, {Moment} from 'moment';
```

In your tsconfig.json ,you should have **allowSyntheticDefaultImports :true**

Comment: That's right, but depending on your module loader/bundler, you also need to specify `"esModuleInterop": true`. That actually implicitly sets `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true`, but it doesn't hurt to be explicit. The former only affects type checking, so your module tool has to do the work, while the latter actually synthesizes the default